# Django model field is showing in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my django admin model(Profile), I am not able to see my StudentID field declared in django model.
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    StudentID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='SID')
    Branch = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Departments, default="CSE")
    YearOfStudy = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ContactNumber = PhoneField(help_text='Contact phone number')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
    parentsContactNumber = PhoneField(help_text="Parent's phone number", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

[image]

Comment: where's your ModelAdmin ?

Comment: NB: Django admin excludes auto PK fields from the admin change form (since they are not editable). If you want to display the value, you'll have to override your admin change_form template.

Comment: You can use model admin to display that StudentId inside list, however the StudentId field won't be available on the form because it is AutoField as @brunodesthuilliers said you need to override admin form template to get id field on form.

Answer (score -1):

To reflect your StudentID in the admin page you must return it in the **str** function

```
    def __str__(self): 
    return self.StudentID
```

Comment: 1/ the `__str__()` magic method MUST return a string (your code will end up raising a TypeError), 2/ this will not make the field appear in the change form.